# Routes in plugin with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a plugin that needs to override the default route for /

The file I have attempting this is at APP/Plugin/Install/Config/routes.php

```
<?php
Router::connect('/', array('plugin' => 'install', 'controller' => 'installer', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Which does not work. I am also loading all plugins in my bootstrap. `CakePlugin::loadAll();`

Am I missing something?

[UPDATE. This file needs to override the main routes.php file in APP/Config/routes.php. Obviously updating the main routes file works and shows the right page, but I am trying to override this file and not modify it directly.]

Comment: try this <?php
Router::connect('/', array('plugin'=>'install','controller' => 'installer', 'action' => 'index')); ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried overriding the default route for a plugin - I have for plain controllers - but I think you'll need `'plugin'=>'install'` or somesuch in your array.

**Edit:**
[This bit about plugins in the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html#plugin-configuration) might apply, I think your loadAll should look something like this:

```
CakePlugin::loadAll(array(
    'Install' => array('routes' => true)
));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to route to a plugin you should specify it, Cake will not guess what plugin you want.

```
Router::connect('/', array('plugin' => 'install', 'controller' => 'installer', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Routes, that are added later, will be overwriten by the route first defined.

e.g. the route '/' is usually defined in the app/config/routes.php
if you want to overwrite that from your 'app/plugin/YOURPLUGIN/config/routes.php', you need to use 'Router::promote'.

See [documentation on Router::promote](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#Router::promote)

e.g. app/plugin/YOURPLUGIN/config/routes.php

```
Router::connect(
'/',
array(
    'plugin' => 'YOURPLUGIN',
    'controller' => 'YOURPLUGIN_CONTROLLER',
    'action' => 'index'
));
Router::promote();
```

This puts the route of the plugin before the original route for '/', thus matching it first.